# What is "pack name" in UNIX file system (superblock)?

Tags: unix, filesystems

In the FS superblock declarations of (ancient) UNIX systems one can find a member called **s_fpack[6]**. I found no real description of it.

```
s_name holds the name of the filesystem (where it is mounted, more or less) and 
s_fpack contains which volume this filesystem is. The s_fpack field is singularly
useless, but is provided for utility compatibility.

or

s_fname is the name of the file system and s_fpack is the name of the pack.
```

**Any idea what is meant by "pack name" ?**

NB: in the XFS both FS name and pack name are marked obsolete (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xfs_db.8.html)

```
   struct    filsys
   {
     ushort  s_isize;          /* size in blocks of i-list */
     daddr_t s_fsize;          /* size in blocks of entire volume */
     short   s_nfree;          /* number of addresses in s_free */
     daddr_t s_free[NICFREE];  /* free block list */
     short   s_ninode;         /* number of i-nodes in s_inode */
     o_ino_t s_inode[NICINOD]; /* free i-node list */
     char    s_flock;          /* lock during free list */
                               /* manipulation */
     char    s_ilock;          /* lock during i-list manipulation */
     char    s_fmod;           /* super block modified flag */
     char    s_ronly;          /* mounted read-only flag */
     time_t  s_time;           /* last super block update */
     short   s_dinfo[4];       /* device information */
     daddr_t s_tfree;          /* total free blocks*/
     o_ino_t s_tinode;         /* total free i-nodes */
     char    s_fname[6];       /* file system name */
-->  char    s_fpack[6];       /* file system pack name */
     long    s_fill[12];       /* ADJUST to make */
                               /* sizeof filsys be 512 */
     long    s_state;          /* file system state */
     long    s_magic;          /* magic number to denote new file
                               /* system */
     long    s_type;           /* type of new file system */
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question, this is much more of a history question.

Back in the past, hard disks were presented in [packs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_pack). A pack might be loosely equated to a physical disk, or more modernly, a logical volume from a volume manager.

The name of this field was originally to represent the pack the file system is on. In more modern times, it could represent the disk or volume that the drive comes from.

In older times the file system layout *could* be affected by the pack physical structure, which could be used to tune the performance of the file system.

I'm going to lean a little bit into opinion here, and state that nowadays there is less relevance for this piece of information, as it is less likely to affect the performance of the file system, which is the reason why it might be deprecated, or not even present in various other file systems.